# Swift. Receive remote control events to work with MPNowPLayingInfoCenter

Tags: ios, swift, remote-control, mpnowplayinginfocenter

As I understand, in order to show music player on lock screen, writing the following code is not enough.

```
override func viewDidAppear(animated: Bool) {    
var mpic = MPNowPlayingInfoCenter.defaultCenter()
    mpic.nowPlayingInfo = [
        MPMediaItemPropertyTitle:"This Is a Test",
        MPMediaItemPropertyArtist:"Matt Neuburg"
    ]
}
```

My app also should be able to receive [remote control events](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/EventHandling/Conceptual/EventHandlingiPhoneOS/Remote-ControlEvents/Remote-ControlEvents.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40009541-CH7)

So, how to do that in Swift?

I found  this from [Apple Documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/EventHandling/Conceptual/EventHandlingiPhoneOS/Remote-ControlEvents/Remote-ControlEvents.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40009541-CH7), but it's for Objective-C.

```
- (void)viewDidAppear:(BOOL)animated {
    [super viewDidAppear:animated];

    // Turn on remote control event delivery
    [[UIApplication sharedApplication] beginReceivingRemoteControlEvents];

    // Set itself as the first responder
    [self becomeFirstResponder];
}


- (void)viewWillDisappear:(BOOL)animated {

    // Turn off remote control event delivery
    [[UIApplication sharedApplication] endReceivingRemoteControlEvents];

    // Resign as first responder
    [self resignFirstResponder];

    [super viewWillDisappear:animated];
}

- (void)remoteControlReceivedWithEvent:(UIEvent *)receivedEvent {

    if (receivedEvent.type == UIEventTypeRemoteControl) {

        switch (receivedEvent.subtype) {

            case UIEventSubtypeRemoteControlTogglePlayPause:
                [self playOrStop: nil];
                break;

            case UIEventSubtypeRemoteControlPreviousTrack:
                [self previousTrack: nil];
                break;

            case UIEventSubtypeRemoteControlNextTrack:
                [self nextTrack: nil];
                break;

            default:
                break;
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just found solution on GitHub
https://github.com/mattneub/Programming-iOS-Book-Examples/tree/master/bk2ch14p643ducking/ch27p912ducking

Comment: The event processing code is in ViewController.swift